# Does anyone know the name of the song played in these scenes from Dagashi Kashi?

Tags: music, dagashi-kashi

In [this clip from Dagashi Kashi](https://youtu.be/QeQRSHKDbCA?t=15) the song starts at 0:15, and in [this clip](https://youtu.be/TgIzdADE_jg?t=58) it starts at around 0:58. I tried searching for it but couldn't find it anywhere. Does anyone know the name of the song?

**EDIT:** Both clips are from season 2. First clip is from episode 12. The scene is at the start of the episode around 0:38. The second clip is from episode 4. And starts around 11:35 in that episode.

Comment: Sounds like some OST. You'll probably have to wait until the OST CD comes out. (A cursory search amazon jp only shows S1 material)

Answer (score 1):

Fuyu no Ame is the first song, it is from the second season soundtrack.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.

Comment: the source is the second soundtrack and me listening to it, there is as such no official list giving a detailed breakdown of songs featured every episode.